# Session with domain in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, session

I have a new project maintenance website (Codeigniter framework).
I downloaded source code from the server and set it up locally with domain bsd.test

I tried to login but failed. After I change domain locally to the same domain as the server, I login successfully.

How to config it so it runs with domain bsd.test in local?

Comment: Could you please add a bit more about how you use session (e.g. are you using session driver, like database driver?)

Comment: it's very likely that you need to change `config/config.php` so that it reads `$config['base_url'] = 'http://bsd.test/';` and also check within the same file that `$config['cookie_*']` has settings that match those of your local environment including forcing secure protocols, being restricted to one domain only, etc. The file itself is pretty self explanatory with a lot of comments that'll guide you to the correct settings (and if not, please post the relevant parts of `config/config.php` here so we can give you a hand)